# Validate secondary form using jquery validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I've got 2 forms on one page (add a product to your basket on http://www.bumblebeezflorist.com/). You can see the fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/jeepstone/S5Fnn/

Where you have the Delivery Estimator I would like to validate that something has been entered before someone clicks on the Checkout link.

As I already have the jquery validate library on the site I was planning to use this. So far I have:

```
if($('#cartForm').length > 0) {
    $('#proceedCheckout').on('click', function (event) {
        console.log('HSA');
        $('#changeCountry').validate({
            errorClass: 'alert-error'
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

The validation works correctly if you tab out of the postcode field, but if you click the checkout button, the validation doesn't fire. How can I do this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code:

```
if($('#cartForm').length > 0) {
    $('#proceedCheckout').on('click', function (event) {
        console.log('HSA');
        $('#changeCountry').validate({ // <-- move out of here
            errorClass: 'alert-error'
        });
        event.preventDefault();  // <-- should always be first in a function
    });
}
```

[`.validate()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options) is supposed to be used to initialize the plugin (with its options) on the form on DOM ready.  Since you're re-intitializing on every click, you're seeing unexpected behavior.

You were also targeting `#changeCountry` by `id` where no `id` existed, so I added the corresponding `id` to both `form` tags.

Whenever you have two forms and one form's submission depends upon another's validation status, use [the plugin's `.valid()` method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid) to test the other form.

Try something more like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // call .validate() to initialize the plugin
    $('#changeCountry').validate({
        errorClass: 'alert-error'
    });

    // on click, test the form using .valid()
    $('#proceedCheckout').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if ($('#changeCountry').valid()) {
            $('#cartForm').submit(); // passes validation
        } else {
            // failed validation
        }
    });

});
```

**Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/B9d8A/**

[`$('#changeCountry').validate()` initializes the validate plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options) on the `form` with `id` `#changeCountry`.

[`$('#changeCountry').valid()` programmatically triggers an actual validation test](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid) and returns a `true/false` boolean value.

**Full documentation:**

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Comment: Excellent answer! I was missing the valid() called. Silly thing to miss really. Further compounded by my fiddle missing the field ID. Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

Why are you conditionally adding the click event to the button?

I'd have the cart test inside the click event so that you don't run into any problems with the click event being correctly assigned to the button.

```
$('#proceedCheckout').on('click', function (event) {
   console.log('HSA');
   if($('#cartForm').length > 0) {
     $('#changeCountry').validate({ errorClass: 'alert-error'  });
     event.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

Comment: `.validate()` is for _initializing_ the plugin on the form; it's not for "testing" the form's present status.

Comment: Great, thanks for the info, that'll possibly be useful for me later.  However, what the .validate() does is completely irrelevant to the point of my post, which was questioning the reasoning behind the adding the 'click' event to #proceedCheckout conditionally, b/c conditionally adding events is typically questionable design.